# How to identify if a key is down on hover?

Tags: jquery, events, jquery-events

I would like to show one `div` only when another `div` is hovered **and the Space Bar is down**. I tried to use `keyCode` and `which` properties of the event, but none of them worked. Though, I could create an example for <kbd>CTRL</kbd> key pressed rather than the Space Bar, as you can see also [here](http://jsfiddle.net/EFh9q/).

How should I change the code so it will work with Space Bar (or any other key) down?

HTML:

```
<div class='a'></div>
<div class='b'></div>
```

CSS:

```
body {
    position: relative;
}
div {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    position: absolute;
}
.a {
    background: #777;
    left: 50px;
    top: 30px;
}
.b {
    display: none;
    background: #000;
    left: 250px;
    top: 100px;
}
```

JS:

```
$(function() {
    $('div').hover(function(e) {
        if (e.ctrlKey) {
            $('.b').show();
        }
    }, function() {
        if ($('.b').is(':visible')) $('.b').hide();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can make use of the fact that **[`.hover()`](http://api.jquery.com/hover/)** binds 2 handlers. One for mouseenter and one for mouseleave.

Bind a **[`.keydown()`](http://api.jquery.com/keydown/)** on mouseenter and simply **[`.unbind()`](http://api.jquery.com/unbind/)** it on mouseleave:

```
$(function() {

      // Define the mouseenter and mouseleave handlers with hover
    $("div.a").hover(function() {

          // Show other div if a key is pressed.
          // You can of course check for on particular key.
        $(document).keydown(function() {
            $("div.b").show();
        });

    }, function() {

         // unbind the keydown handler on mouseleave
       $(document).unbind("keydown");

       $("div.b").hide();
    });
});​
```

### **[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/EKA5F/)**

An important note is that **[`.hover()`](http://api.jquery.com/hover/)** will work even if the window hasn't been focused, but **[`.keydown()`](http://api.jquery.com/keydown/)** will only work if the window is in focus.

Answer (score 0):

On hover i'd be setting a flag and then on leaving hover state i'd reset the flag.  then when the space bar is pressed you can check whether you are in a hover state.

i'm not sure that hover and space can be trapped in the way you would like.

**edit**

in jquery you could combine event.which and event.hover on the same element and maybe you could chain them.

i'll take a quick look but i don't like your chances.

**edit 2**

the issue is that a div won't get any key events.  i think you need to attach a key listener to the document and a hover on the div and keep a flag.

you can chain events like this `$('#myElement").bind('hover keydown', function(){});`

Comment: But why it does work with CTRL key and cannot work with other key ?

Comment: I believe it's because the ctrl key isn't a displayable chr and so is trapped by elements and bubbled up.  the div has no way to handle a displayable chr and so doesn't bother with it.